# When designing an activity-based authorization system, how should additional conditional checks be handled?

Tags: design, rest, api, security, microservices

When designing an activity-based authorization system, how should additional conditional checks be handled?

For example, I have the following authority:

```
VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS
```

which allows the user to hit the endpoint

```
GET /company/{companyName}/transactions
```

However, what if my authority `VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS` has other restrictions based on the activity parameters that in fact make the authority effectively `VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS(companyName=company_a)`. I don't want to encode that information into the authority system, and end up with the following new authority:

```
VIEW_COMPANY_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_COMPANY_A
```

The above authority seems to mix up the filtering of the views and the authority itself which makes everything somewhat tedious and inflexible.

In another example, I have the following authority:

```
APPROVE_TRANSACTION
```

which allows the user to hit the endpoint:

```
POST /company/{companyName}/transactions/{id}/approvals
```

But what if the approval can only be done if the `transaction.amount < maxAmount` in which case, it's even harder to encode this into a new hardcoded authority.

Note that these authorities may also be included in a JWT token, so they must somewhat *transferable* as well.

What's the best way to design such a system? Any tips?